# How would I add a query filter to the Iteration Tracking Board?

Tags: javascript, rally

So I have the source code for the Iteration Tracking Board on Rally. All I want to do is to add a query filter that is similar to the Portfolio Hierarchy app or the Portfolio Kanban Board.

[image]

If this is possible, I think that I may need to add it in the javascript code as a plugin and I was wondering how that should be coded.

Is this correct? Or can I not even add the filter as a plugin because it is not defined as one in Rally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some quick background, here is a guide on working with settings in apps: https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0rc2/doc/#!/guide/settings

This is a 2 parter.  First, you'll need to add the query settings field to your app.  Since this field is commonly used across apps there is a handy preconfigured on you can just reference by type:

```
getSettingsFields: function() {
    var fields = this.callParent(arguments);
    //...
    //existing code omitted for brevity
    //...
    fields.push({type: 'query'});
    return fields;
}
```

Then you'll need to actually use that setting to filter the data shown.  Add the following to the cardBoardConfig object:

```
storeConfig: {
    filters: this.getSetting('query') ?
        [Rally.data.QueryFilter.fromQueryString(this.getSetting('query'))] : []
}
```